# ReactiveCommand.Execute not triggering IsExecuting

Tags: reactiveui

I'm subscribed to the IsExecuting of a command:

```
LoginCommand.IsExecuting.Subscribe(x => Log("Logging in"));
```

and it works fine when my Command is invoked by InvokeCommand but when I call it by:

```
LoginCommand.Execute();
```

The IsExecuting observable is not triggered.

This works:

```
Observable.Start(() => { }).InvokeCommand(LoginCommand);
```

Does someone know why the IsExecuting property doesn't change when calling the Execute method? I'm trying to unit test the command so I thought this would be the best way to execute it from tests.

Comment: The for posting something that does work.  In my view I subscribe to some ReactiveCommands where action needs to take place in the view in addition to the viewmodel.  If anyone has a better solution than InvokeCommand, please post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the upgrade to ReactiveUI 7.0, the `Execute()` method changed. Right now it does not trigger the command immediately. Instead, it returns a cold `IObservable` to which you have to subscribe in order to make stuff happen.

```
LoginCommand.Execute().Subscribe();
```

Check in the write up about the changes in RxUI 7.0 in the [release notes](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases/tag/7.0.0). Ctrl+F "ReactiveCommand is Better". It states explicitly:

> the Execute exposed by ReactiveCommand is reactive (it returns IObservable). It is therefore lazy and won't do anything unless something subscribes to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to execute an `ReactiveCommand`, you can do it like this:

```cs
RxApp.MainThreadScheduler.Schedule(Unit.Default, (scheduler, state) => 
       ViewModel.MyCommand.Execute(state).Subscribe());
```

You can then Subscribe to it like this:

```cs
this.WhenActivated(d => { 

    MyCommand
        .Select(_ => this)
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .ExecuteOn(RxApp.TaskScheduler)
        .Subscribe(viewModel => {
            // ... 
        })
        .DisposeWith(d); 
});
```